# I am having trouble identifying the manufacturer of this bike

Tags: frames

What brand is this logo? Can anyone identify this? [image]

Comment: http://www.k2bike.com/index.php?page=search

Comment: @WTHarper You should repost that as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

The headbadge says K2. Here is the [K2 website](http://www.k2bike.com/index.php?page=search)

Answer (score 3):

That's the logo for K2 Bike - the sticker above is probably a retailer sticker.  K2 Bike was started in 1998 after the K2 organisation decided to merge their Ski, Skate and Bike brands under one brand.  The bike brand was a company that K2 had previously bought called Girvin Mountain Sports who sold the "Proflex" range of bikes.

(I was at the launch party!)