# Headtube Badges

Tags: reference, identify-this-bike

It would be helpful to have a collection of common head tube badges to aid in identifying bicycles.

**Guidelines:**

- Include a photo! (Credit photo where appropriate)
- A brief summary of the logo: manufacture, area, date logo was used and on what bikes
- It is okay to give specific information such as an exact year and model of bicycle. As more users lend their expertise this information can be generalized.
- Edit previous answers: add different logos used by that manufacturer, improve summaries, etc.
- Even badges with the manufacturer clearly identified can be helpful (ie. for dating purposes or if someone is trying to match a silhouette or damaged badge).
- This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_badge) page is a good resource to start with, but here we can add more information, such as when a badge was used and for what models.

**Contents** (as of 2/12/14):

[Public](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/headtube-badges/20279#20279)
[Raleigh](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/headtube-badges/20306#20306)

Comment: I thought this would be helpful for identifying bikes / models, and tried to follow the format of the [terminology index](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index). Also similar to [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/167/bike-sharing-services-and-systems).

Past questions which could have been helped: [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17999/i-am-having-trouble-identifying-the-manufacturer-of-this-bike) and [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/just-bought-a-vintage-sprinter-gran-touring-where-to-find-info).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Public Head Tube Badge]

Manufacturer: [Public Bikes](http://www.publicbikes.com) (San Francisco, 2013)

Bike(s): R16 (Road bike) and other models

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Manufacturer: Ralreigh (Heron Badge)

Bike(s): Found on late 70's, early 80's road bike